# Convert folder backups to Git repo

Tags: git

I have inherited a project that was not developed using any SCM whatsoever. Instead I have a series of folders that look like:

```
my-project.201109011234
my-project.201110010908
my-project.201202040454
my-project.201203011123
...and so on...
```

Each folder is a complete copy of the source code, and the folder is named after the timestamp of when the copy was made. Changes abound between each copy, i.e. files and folders added, removed, renamed and file contents changed.

Is there any sort of tool, where I can feed it a list of folders and it will basically Create a Git repo for me, where each folder becomes a commit? After which I would hope that Git knows exactly what changed between each commit?

Thanks Adam.

Comment: I would use a shell script. What system are you on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds to me like a very particular problem to solve (i.e. there probably isn't a tried and tested method to integrate something like that into git).

That said, a solution could easily be devised with a bit of shell/python/xyz scripting. the steps would be these:

- make an empty git repo
- make a list of the archives, sorted chronologically
- for each archive:

  - delete contents of project directory (everything except .git directory)
  - unzip archive into project dir
  - run "git add -u ." in the directory
  - run "git add -f ." in the directory
  - extract/generate commit message based on archive name
  - commit current state of the project dir

This solution has many limitations (like not performing each commit on the archive date) but depending on what is important to you, you can adapt the script.

Comment: To set the date for each commit, simply export `GIT_AUTHOR_DATE` and `GIT_COMMITTER_DATE` environment variables: see https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-commit-tree.html (but see also http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-and-Other-Systems-Migrating-to-Git)

Comment: Will this cope with files that were in revision A, but were removed in revision B? i.e. will show they were removed in the history?

Comment: @adamretter, yes. This is what the "git add -u" does: it updates the index with removed files.

Comment: @utnapistim Perfect, that is what I hoped from reading the man page. Just wanted to check.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to whatever utnapistim has replied, you can change the commit and the author date as per your archive dates.

There are two options:
 1. The following option will change the date for all the further commits

```
GIT_AUTHOR_DATE='[Date]' GIT_COMMITTER_DATE='[Date]' git commit -m "[Message]"
```

2. For individual commits , you can do the following:

   `git commit --date "[Whatever date you want]"`